# ¿Por qué se llaman "corredores de bolsa" si no corren?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

¿Por qué se les llama a  "corredores de bolsa"? ¿Porque tienen que correr mucho en esa profesión? Pero parece que siempre gritan, por lo que se podría llamarles "gritadores de bolsa"? :)

> **Corredor de bolsa** es una persona jurídica o natural que previo encargo tiene autorización para asesorar o realizar directamente inversiones o transacciones de valores en los mercados financieros y comerciales.
>
> <sub>Del artículo [Agente de bolsa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agente_de_bolsa) en Wikipedia</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Corredor*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AxUOPpI) tiene muchas acepciones, pero de entre ellas yo destacaría dos:

> 3. m. y f. Persona que corre en competiciones deportivas.
>
> 5. m. pasillo (‖ pieza de paso de un edificio).

Es decir, por un lado está la vertiente de correr, desplazar, y por otro la de pasillo, canal.

El corredor de bolsa entraría en el segundo grupo, como vemos en su definición en la misma palabra:

> 4. m. y f. Mandatario que, como comerciante acreditado, actúa vendiendo o comprando por cuenta de uno o varios.

Es decir, y retorciendo algo las palabras, el *corredor de bolsa* ejerce de *pasillo* o *canal* entre la bolsa y las personas que quieren operar en ella.

Comment: Yo pensaría más bien que originalmente este agente corría para acá y para allá.  Mira por ejemplo la definición 9: *hacer correrías en tierra de enemigos.*

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!